# Rotating 3D figure

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, libgdx

I need to click the mouse button you can rotate the figure in 2 axes. When you release the mouse button Figure be rotated in the original position. With a small turning everything goes as it should, but at a heavy rotation (<180) of the figure does not return to its original position.

I do not see any mistakes. Help me.

```
public class WaitActionScren extends Base3dGameScreen {

    private static final int DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE = 5;
    private int sumRotateX = 0, sumRotateY = 0;
    private boolean isUp = false;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param game {@link MagicSphere} instance.
     */
    public WaitActionScren(MagicSphere game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        bitmapFontCache.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new TouchEvents());
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(instanceSphere, lights);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        if (isUp) {
            int inertValue = getInertValue(sumRotateX);
            instanceSphere.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, inertValue);
            System.err.println("rotate_x : " + inertValue);
            sumRotateX += inertValue;

            inertValue = getInertValue(sumRotateY);
            instanceSphere.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, inertValue);
            System.err.println("rotate_y : " + inertValue);
            sumRotateY += inertValue;
        }
    }

    // TODO non static.
    private static int getInertValue(int sumRotate) {
        if(sumRotate > 0) {
            if (sumRotate < DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE) {
                return -sumRotate;
            }
            return -DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE;
        }

        if(sumRotate < 0) {
            if (sumRotate > -DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE) {
                return -sumRotate;
            }
            return DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE;
        }

        return 0;
    } 

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    class TouchEvents implements InputProcessor {
        private int oldX = 0, oldY = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            oldX = 0;
            oldY = 0;
            isUp = true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            if (oldX != 0 || oldY != 0) {
                float change;
                change = screenX - oldX;
                instanceSphere.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, change);
                System.err.println("X: " + change);
                sumRotateX += change;
                change = screenY - oldY;
                instanceSphere.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, change);
                System.err.println("X: " + change);
                sumRotateY += change;
            }
            oldX = screenX;
            oldY = screenY;
            isUp = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "does not return to its original position" do you mean; stays where it is, or moves to the third position; different from the original positio

Comment: When you release the mouse button the sphere must Bar over the starting position. It all starts well sphere begins to rotate in the opposite direction. The new position is always different - Depends on initial turn. Please view https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XeDRWWEYzVjBQbm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Glorious, do you have an english translation for that?

Comment: Also, I noticed that if you use only one axis. x or y. then everything is working properly

Comment: Without having the relevant library its hard for me to be sure but I think you might be falling fowl of the order of rotations problem; that being that if you rotate around the x axis by 30 degrees then about the y axis by 30 degrees **that is not the same as** rotating round y then x. So given that you always rotate y then x when you come to undo a rotation you're not really undoing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the relevant library its hard for me to be sure but I think you might be falling fowl of the order of rotations problem; that being that if you rotate around the y axis by 90 degrees then about the z axis by 90 degrees that is not the same as rotating around z then y. So given that you always rotate about y then about x when you come to undo a rotation you're not really undoing it, you're performing annother rotation.

To demonstrate this, lets start with a vector pointed along the x axis, and we're going to rotate 90 degrees about y and z, but in different orders

## First about y then about z

[image]
[image]
[image]

## First about z then about y

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Conclusion

As you can see the order of operations is very important, so if you first rotate x then y, in order to undo that you need to rotate -y then -x.

Comment: Thank. I also had these suspicions. But by changing the order of operations to achieve success did not happen. It appears this is due to the fact that the return of the rotation step is constant. I will try to use method setToRotate this should work, but a little more difficult.

Comment: @Vladmir Yes, I think if you just want to reset the position I'd not be trying to modify the current rotation but setting a new rotation (of unrotated).

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the desired result. I hope this will be useful for someone.

```
public class WaitActionScren extends Base3dGameScreen {

    private static final float DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE = 7f;
    private float sumY = 0;
    private float sumX = 0;
    private boolean isUp = false;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param game {@link MagicSphere} instance.
     */
    public WaitActionScren(MagicSphere game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        bitmapFontCache.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new TouchEvents());
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(instanceSphere, lights);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        if (isUp) {
            Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion();
            instanceSphere.transform.getRotation(rotation);
            float xInert = getInertValue(sumX);
            float yInert = getInertValue(sumY);
            sumX += xInert;
            sumY += yInert;
            Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(sumY, sumX, 0);
            float len = v3.len();
            v3 = v3.nor();
            rotation.setFromAxis(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, len);
            instanceSphere.transform.set(rotation);
        }
    }

    private float getInertValue(float sumRotate) {
        if(sumRotate > 0.0f) {
            if (sumRotate < DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE) {
                return -sumRotate;
            }
            return -DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE;
        }

        if(sumRotate < 0.0f) {
            if (sumRotate > -DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE) {
                return -sumRotate;
            }
            return DEFAULT_INERT_VALUE;
        }

        return 0;
    } 

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    class TouchEvents implements InputProcessor {
        private float oldX = 0.0f, oldY = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            oldX = screenX;
            oldY = screenY;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            oldX = 0.0f;
            oldY = 0.0f;
            isUp = true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            float changeX;
            float changeY;

            changeX = screenX - oldX;
            changeY = screenY - oldY;
            sumX += changeX;
            sumY += changeY;

            Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(sumY, sumX, 0.0f);
            float length = v3.len();
            v3 = v3.nor();
            Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion();
            instanceSphere.transform.getRotation(rotation);
            rotation.setFromAxis(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, length);
            instanceSphere.transform.set(rotation);

            oldX = screenX;
            oldY = screenY;
            isUp = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```